# Ransack on Gutentag tags- undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Has anybody gotten Ransack to search Gutentag tag_names ? I have had issues making ActsAsTaggableOn work but Gutentag works like a charm, I just need to be able to search on it..

`resource.tag_names` returns a list of tags for `resource`.

I have in my model

```
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
      ['title','content', 'tag_names']
  end
```

the line erroring is `@resources = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page])`

I'm assuming that tag_names is not returning the right data for Ransack. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because there is no column `tag_names` in your table. Thus you need to define `ransackable_attributes` for `gutentag_tags` table, because that is the table whose `name` column is called under the hood. Create an initializer for  gutentag in `config/initializers` directory, name it however you like. In that initializer put the following:

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'gutentag_tags'
  model =  Object.const_get "Gutentag::Tag"
  model.singleton_class.class_eval do
    define_method(:ransackable_attributes) do |auth_object|
      auth_object = nil
      ['name']
    end
  end
end
```

This should do the trick although I haven't tried it myself. Feel free to ask anything in case you meet problems with this piece of code.

Comment: EDIT: Scratch that, I applied your fix to mistaken code originally. It now works well, thank you very much!